# Changing monitor brightness programatically in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, brightness

I'm using Dell inspiron 1564 laptop with Ubuntu 11.10. Here I can change my monior brightness simply via fn+F4/5. But I need a low brightness even lower than the min limit of fn+F4. How can I do it programatically or which shell command to use for that?

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180113 In general: `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 0.5` - replace `HDMI-0` with the output which you want to dim. To find out output names run `xrandr | grep connected`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible to go lower than what the laptop controls get you, but you can programatically change brightness by echoing a value to `/sys/class/backlight/<something>/brightness`.  On my netbook the 'something' is `acpi_video0`.

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
10
$ sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
0
```

Edit: There's also [xbacklight](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xbacklight.1.html), which uses XRandr.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.ubuntuka.com/ubuntu-command-line-tricks-set-1) site, you should be able to alter the brightness by modifying the `/proc/acpi/video/VGA/LCD/brightness` file.

The *valid* brightness levels appear to be:

```
levels:  12 25 37 50 62 75 87 100
```

So modifying that file accordingly *should* do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it by following command `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 f4.b=00`, here you can enter value from 00 to ff in hexadecimal, [00 = bright and ff = dull]

for more details go through the following link : http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-increasedecrease-brightness-on.html